# Service is auto killed by the system and is later restarted in Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, service, android-2.3-gingerbread, armv6

Platform: Arm11 MX53 Android 2.3.4

My Service is auto killed by the system and is later restarted.
In my service I need to keep receive some message from other devices.

I don't know why the system often killed and restarted my main service.

How can I avoid the system to kill my service?

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: in settings you have an option to kill background services, just disable it

Comment: Can you tell me more detail? I didn't find the option. Is that in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I think, your problem is , your activity is finished() so the service associated with it is also terminated. Have a check

Comment: Is that means I should startService at each activity to avoid system auto finished() the one which do startService's activity ? I have many activity but just startService on the first one.

Comment: Yeah there are different types of services , You can look in to it, if you want to keep the service running even after the created acivity expires you can look in to AIDL services